# How to add a custom text field inside product edit page?

Tags: magento2, admin, custom-field

I want to add a text field which would actually store a link to my vendors' product  URL. It will be used by management only and should not be visible to customers. How to do that? I am using `Magento 2.3.3`

Comment: You can create a product attrbute and add that attribute to product arbitrate set refer - https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/add-attributes-to-product-in-magento-2/

Comment: @Ranganathan I have not thought about that. That would be a possible solution. But still prefer to save it as a field.

Comment: add product url in text field in product detail page or not visible customer right ?

Comment: Yes exactly...Magento has a default feature 'product attrbute'. So you can add field in product edit form.